# Permission denied for root user

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I am currently using Capistrano to deploy a Rails application on Ubuntu 16.04. I have the configuration to use the root user `master` but am getting the following error when running the deployment check.

```
01 mkdir -p /var/www/pdtracker/shared /var/www/pdtracker/releases
01 mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/pdtracker’
01 : Permission denied
01 mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/pdtracker’: Permission denied
```

Not sure if I need to post more information as this is my first Ubuntu question. Should I change folder permissions perhaps? Any suggestions?

This is the command I am running that produces the error:
`sudo cap production deploy:check`

Comment: What is "the root user master"? Is the user master or is it root?

Comment: Please include *the* exact command you are typing. You're probably running it as normal user.

Comment: Have you tried a `sudo -H -u www-data <command>` this should run the commands as user www-data which has access to write to that folder

Comment: @JohnOrion My apologies, I am running this as sudo.

Comment: yeah i saw the edit ... but .. again the `-H -u www-data` added to the sudo command runs the command as user www-data which should have access to write to the `www` directory as long as the www directory is owned and grouped by `www-data:www-data`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `Capistrano` yet, but most of the installation guides say that by default the process will be run by the user deploy which we create during the installation.

So i think the user deploy has no permission to create a directory under `/var/www/` and that's why this error occurs.

So changing the user of `/var/www/` to deploy should fix the issue.

So first check if there is `/var/www/`. If no create it using the following command.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/
```

And next change the user of that directory to deploy.

```
sudo chown -R deploy:www-data /var/www/
```

**Note**: Some installation guides say the username as deployer. So you need to make sure that which username you are using.

**For more** : Please refer the ***Authorisation*** section in the official [documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/)